# Hibernate warning - applying in memory! - under the hood? What kind of memory?

Tags: hibernate, pagination, query-performance

I would like to ask about this common warning - HHH000104: firstResult/maxResults specified with collection fetch; applying in memory!

I found a lot of questions related to this problem. But I am not sure about the problem itsefl. So I have some questions.

The first one is about some Hibernate memory scheme? What kind of memory Hibernate uses?
In what kind of memory are some resultSets saved?
What kind of memory is first and second lvl cache?
And finally what is the problem with warning - "applying in memory"? What kind of memory is that? It is slower than "regular memory" hibernate uses and that causes the problem? Are we talking about JVM memory? (It will by probably answered with my previous questions)

Exuse my pell-mell question asking. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you join fetch a collection and use `setFirstResult`/`setMaxResults` on that query, Hibernate will use an inefficient strategy for pagination. If you avoid join fetching collections, hibernate will generate a query that will only fetch the elements that it needs.

Another option would be to use a library like Blaze-Persistence which works on top of JPA that implementes efficient pagination: https://persistence.blazebit.com/documentation/core/manual/en_US/index.html#pagination